# Delete lines on a range by sed command

Tags: bash, sed

I've tried to find some solution on other related post but I'm still here with the same error.
I'm working on a bash script which uses sed command to delete some lines(in a range formed by $linestart $linestop) on file.
I need to use a command like that:

```
sed -i '1,3d' pippo.txt
```

my script.sh is something like that:

```
#!/bin/bash

line = 1

line2 = 3

sed -i "${line},${line2} d" pippo.txt;

exit
```

Can someone help me with this little problem of syntax please?

Comment: Works for me...

Comment: Thanks for shellcheck.net. i've edited some space and lines and now the bash script works. but i don't understand why doesn't work when i call the script by php page. php: <?php $var1 = '2'; $var2 = '4'; $var1 = escapeshellarg($var1); $var2 = escapeshellarg($var2); $output=shell_exec('/home/gtaibi/Documenti/dhcpd.sh $var1 $var2'); ?> bash: #!/bin/bash line=$var1 line2=$var2 sed -i "${line},${line2} d" pippo.txt; exit

Comment: So you have a bash+sed script that works just fine from the command line but not when called from PHP. So.... is the problem more likely to be in the bash+sed itself or in how you're calling it from PHP? If the latter you might want to consider adding a PHP tag and including your PHP code in the question.